# Newton's Method for nonlinear systems

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

What does Newton’s Method for nonlinear
systems reduce to for the linear system Ax = b
where A is a nonsingular matrix?
Like what is the corresponding multivariate function and Jacobian of the System?
Having a hard time with the abstract form

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x):=b-Ax$, 
$$
\nabla f(x)=-A,
$$
so if $x_0$ is an initial guess of the Newton method, the update
$$
x_1=x_0-[\nabla f(x_0)]^{-1}f(x_0)
$$
boils down to
$$
x_1=x_0+A^{-1}(b-Ax_0)=A^{-1}b.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Generally Newton's method says:
$x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$

In this case 
$f(\mathbf x) = A\mathbf x - b$

$\nabla f(\mathbf x) = A$

$\mathbf x_{1} = $$\mathbf x_{0} - \frac{A\mathbf x_0 - b}{A}\\
\mathbf x_{0} - \mathbf x_0 - A^{-1}b\\
A^{-1}b$

Answer (score 1):

Newton's method solves the equation $f(x) = 0$, where $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is differentiable, using the iteration
$$
f(x_n) + f'(x_n)(x_{n+1} - x_n) = 0,
$$
or in other words
$$ x_{n+1} = x_n - f'(x_n)^{-1} f(x_n).
$$

If $f(x) = Ax - b$, then the equation $f(x) = 0$ is equivalent to $Ax = b$, and $f'(x) = A$, so Newton's iteration is
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n - A^{-1}(A x_n - b) = A^{-1} b.
$$
So $x_{n+1}$ is simply $A^{-1} b$, which is the solution to $Ax = b$.

Comment: Thank you for the response, and you did a really good job of explaining that part, but wouldn't the multivariate function then be a matrix which is used to form the Jacobian matrix 0_0